# Cobol Binary File to pandas dataframe issues

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, binaryfiles, cobol

I received a binary cobol file that represents a table. So, knowing that behind this binary data there is a structured table I want to convert it to a pandas dataframe (or whatever multidimensional structure in python, pyspark, parquet, etc...). But I can't.

Here is an example:

I've already know that in my binary file I've received a table with one row and one column representing a month:

| Month |
| --- |
| 202109 |

Within the binary file I see this:

[image]

Here are the different codes I've run to convert this to a data structure in Python with **no** success:

1.) First try:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

file= 'PMAR7004_01.TXT'

dt = np.dtype([('MONTH','i')])
data = np.fromfile(file, dtype=dt)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Result

| MONTH |
| --- |
| -235736846 |
| 63984 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |

[pandas dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MryUZ.png)

**Second Try:**

```
dt = np.dtype([('MONTH','O')])
data = np.fromfile(file, dtype=dt)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Result:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-3e5630708ccb> in <module>
      2 import numpy as np
      3 dt = np.dtype([('MONTH','O')])
----> 4 data = np.fromfile(file, dtype=dt)
      5 df = pd.DataFrame(data)
      6 df

ValueError: Cannot read into object array
```

**Third Try:**

```
with open(file, 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read().decode('cp500')
data
```

Result:

```
'202109\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

**Fourth Try:**

```
with open(file, 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read().decode('cp500')
print(data)
```

Result:

```
202109
```

As you can see only with the last try I've got something but I guess it's not worth it because imagine that I have more columns.. that only works for one column and one row.

I would like to use something as I've used in the first or second try with numpy and pandas but I dont know why I got errors or bad conversions.

Thanks for reading!!

Comment: If that is the entire file, then no, there is no other data.  There's a six-character string and the rest is all zeros.   Do you have other files like this?

Comment: 1) I don't think there is any such thing as a standard for cobol file formatting. The correct way to decode it is going to depend on how the cobol system was implemented. You'll need to post a more substantial example, with multiple rows and columns. 2) The example you posted is exactly 80 characters long, which makes me suspect that this is a format where each row is represented by 80 characters, and it is a fixed width format.

Comment: Wouldn't a Cobol file use the EBCDIC character encoding?

Comment: Do you have the Cobol Copybook that describes the file ???

Comment: @DYZ a "COBOL file" would not be in any specific Encoding.
If this file was generated on a "big iron" or another environment that uses EBCDIC it possibly would have that encoding - if the file was transferred to PC with conversion (old-school would have been FTP in text mode) then it would be plain ASCII.

But COBOL stores numeric values in a lot of different "binary" ways, depending on the definition - so Bruce's question is the most important one to answer before anything reasonable can be answered.